# let rm truncate files

Tags: linux, permissions, solaris, acl, xattr

A friend of mine has one directory (/var/mail) on his Linux machine where `rm` seems to truncate files if he has no write permissions on the directory. I like this feature and wonder how could I do the same on my Linux box?

This is the behavior what I want:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/nase
$ echo "something" > /tmp/nase/bla
$ chmod ugo-w /tmp/nase
# ...do some more tricks with /tmp/nase ...

$ rm /tmp/nase/bla
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/nase/bla’: Permission denied
# but the file is truncated now:
$ stat -c '%s' /tmp/nase/bla
0
```

On my friends machine /var/mail is an NFS mount with these permissions:

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 root postdrop 4096 Dec  8  2005
```

The NFS server is probably a SUN machine.

One more general technical NFS question: Does the "permission denied" error come from the client only or from server?

Comment: Just make a function called rm, check the permissions of the dir, if you have exec access run real rm, if not then copy /dev/null into the file.

Comment: Or just use `> file`.

Comment: @terdon but do they "know" `CLOBBER`?

Comment: @terdon Does that work on everything? I can never remember.

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: I know how to truncate files  but I really wondered what's going on there. However now after some more debugging it seems that the postfix or a pop/imap server seems to watch these mbox files and truncate it very quickly if I write random stuff into the file. So seems that there is no such unlink-auto-truncate feature ;)